# jQuery call outside namespace

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery plugin X and inside the plugin I have a function test();

My problem is how to call the function test in plugin X from my document..

```
 $("#abc").html('<a href="jQuery.X.test()">test</a>');
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a simple solution?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess plugin code will be very helpful in that case. Can you post a small snapshot of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set `href` to JavaScript (you *could* if you prefix it with `javascript:` but don't.) You can do something like this instead:

```
$('#abc').html('<a href="#">test</a>').find('a').click(jQuery.X.test);
```

What it does:

- Get the `#abc` element
- Set its HTML to an anchor element
- Select the anchor element
- Attach a click event to the anchor element

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember it would be jQuery.test(), not jQuery.X.test()

Comment: could you post some of your plugin code? I understand that its a custom build plugin, is that right?